# Set default display value for Symfony2 form field

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I've got a form with some display only fields in it. These fields are usually DateTime values... but when empty/null I would like to display the string "never".

EDIT:
To be more explicit: The field should show the DateTime value from the database and if null the string 'never' should be displayed.

How should I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Symfony2 Data Transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) :

- In the `transform()` function you can check if your date is `null` and then return the 'never' string. Otherwise return a **string** representation of your date.
- In the `reverseTransform()` function you can check if the string is 'never' and then construct a `null` `DateTime` object. Otherwise, you transform the given string into a valid `DateTime` object with something like 'strtotime()` PHP function.